# Textures not being imported with .obj

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I downloaded a blend file with a car mesh that had textures on it online. I opened it, deleted a few meshes, then exported as .obj. But when i imported it as an .obj into another project it didn't import the textures from the .mtl file it generated when it was exported. Why is that? Did I do something wrong when I exported it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like going to append, opening the .blend file, then choosing objects, then the car and all of that works, it imports the objects and the textures.